# HTML does not use CSS rules

Tags: css, html

I'm new to CSS and I have this problem where my HTML does not use some of the CSS rules I defined.
I have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="sample", lang="he">
<head>
    <title>Project</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="AppController as app">
        <div class="peoplelist", ng-repeat="person in app.people.data">
            <p class="name">{{person.first + ' ' + person.last}}</p>
            <p class="id">{{person.id}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this css:

```
p.name {
    font-family: "David";
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0rem;
    float: right;
}

p.id: {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0rem;
    float: right;
}

div.peoplelist: {
    margin: 5rem;
    float: right;
}
```

When I open the HTML in my browser (chrome) I can see that the first rule (p.name) is used but the other 2 are not, the browser ignored it. When I checked it (Ctrl+Shift J) I saw that the rule was not associated with the element.

I can't seem to find an answer online.
Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Tnx

Comment: Do not use , to separate attributes. Use spaces

Comment: Please use a decent IDE to prevent yourself from getting into such errors in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `:` at the end of the rule. The first rule is correct. Remove the `:` at the end:

```css
p.id: {}
----^
div.peoplelist: {}
--------------^
```

Remove the above said `:` from the rules. Your final one should look like:

```css
p.id {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0rem;
    float: right;
}

div.peoplelist {
    margin: 5rem;
    float: right;
}
```

And one more thing. For the **HTML** attributes, there's no comma!

```
<html ng-app="sample", lang="he">
<!-------------------^
```

Remove that! Use spaces:

```
<html ng-app="sample" lang="he">
```